# SELECT top 5 SUMs (one per customer) for each month in range

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, ranking

I have a query that pulls out month/year totals for customers, and add the ntile ranking. If I were to be able to pull out the max subtotal for ntile 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, I would ALMOST get what I'm after, but I do not know how to proceed.

For example, the result I want would look something like:

```
Month   Year   CustomerCode   SubTotal   ntile
1       2012   CCC            131.45     1
1       2012   CCC            342.95     2
1       2012   ELITE          643.92     3
1       2012   CCC            1454.05    4
1       2012   CCC            12971.78   5
2       2012   CCC            135.99     1
2       2012   CCI            370.47     2
2       2012   NOC            766.84     3
2       2012   ELITE          1428.26    4
2       2012   VBC            5073.20    5
3       2012   CCC            119.02     1
3       2012   CCC            323.78     2
3       2012   HUCC           759.66     3
3       2012   ELITE          1402.95    4
3       2012   CCC            7964.20    5
```

EXCEPT - I would expect ranking to be different customers like for month 2, but my base query isn't giving me that result - and I obviously don't know how to get it in T-SQL on SQL SERVER 2005 - in fact I'm not sure what I'm getting.

My next option is to pull a DataTable in C# and do some gymnastics to get there, but there has to be an easier way :)

My base query is

```
SELECT 
i.DateOrdered
,LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))) AS [Month]   
,LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))) AS [Year]   
,c.CustomerCode 
,SUM(i.Jobprice) AS Subtotal  
,NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY SUM(i.JobPrice)) AS [ntile]
FROM Invoices i 
JOIN 
Customers c 
ON i.CustomerID = c.ID 
WHERE i.DateOrdered >= '1/1/2012'
AND i.DateOrdered <= '9/30/2012' 
GROUP BY YEAR(i.DateOrdered),  MONTH(i.DateOrdered), i.DateOrdered, c.CustomerCode
ORDER BY LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))),   
TRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))),     
SUM(i.JobPrice), c.CustomerCode ASC
```

I'd really appreciate help getting this right.

Thanks in advance

Cliff

Comment: As an aside, `DATEPART(MONTH,...)` could be replaced with `MONTH(...)`, and you don't really need those `STR()` calls around `MONTH()` and `YEAR()`. You may also not need the `LTRIM()`s either. (At least, you *can* omit `LTRIM` in GROUP BY, leaving them in SELECT if they are necessary)

Comment: Do you want to make sure that there are no more than 5 distinct *customers* per month or that there are no more than 5 distinct *sums* per month in the output? In other words, if two customers have the same top daily total, do you want them to count as one (like both are #3) or two (like #3 and #4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read you correctly, what you are after is

For each month in the range,
Show 5 customers who have the greatest SUMs in that month
And against each customer, show the corresponding SUM.

In that case, this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ac4a/4/0) creates a sample table and runs the query that gives you the output described above.  If you wanted to see what's in the created tables, just do simple SELECTs on the right panel.

The query is:

```
;     WITH G as -- grouped by month and customer
(
    SELECT DATEADD(D,1-DAY(i.DateOrdered),i.DateOrdered) [Month],
           c.CustomerCode,
           SUM(i.Jobprice) Subtotal
      FROM Invoices i
      JOIN Customers c ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
     WHERE i.DateOrdered >= '1/1/2012' AND i.DateOrdered <= '9/30/2012'
  GROUP BY DATEADD(D,1-DAY(i.DateOrdered),i.DateOrdered), c.CustomerCode
)
    SELECT MONTH([Month]) [Month],
           YEAR([Month]) [Year],
           CustomerCode,
           SubTotal,
           Rnk [Rank]
      FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (partition by [Month] order by Subtotal desc) Rnk
      FROM G
) X
     WHERE Rnk <= 5
  ORDER BY Month, Rnk
```

To explain, the first part (WITH block) is just a fancy way of writing a subquery, that GROUPs the data by month and Customer.  The expression `DATEADD(D,1-DAY(i.DateOrdered),i.DateOrdered)` turns every date into the FIRST day of that month, so that the data can be easily grouped by month.  The next subquery written in traditional form adds a RANK column within each month by the subtotal, which is finally SELECTed to give the top 5*.

Note that RANK allows for equal rankings, which may end up showing 6 customers for a month, if 3 of them are ranked equally at position 4.  If that is not what you want, then you can change the word `RANK` to `ROW_NUMBER` which will randomly tie-break between equal Subtotals.

Comment: @cyberkiwi - This answer is PERFECT providing the desired rows. Thank you so much. I now need to get this into a stored procedure. I have code to generate the fields for the graph, but this output needs to get into a temp table. This uses CTE generation correct? Where would I put the INTO #Revenues (my first temp table in the sp) - before FROM G? This produces a lot of red squiggly lines in SS Management Studio.

Comment: @cyberkiwi -     "SELECT MONTH([Month]) [Month],
           YEAR([Month]) [Year],
           CustomerCode,
           SubTotal,
           Rnk [Rank]
      INTO #Revenues
      FROM" - I placed it here and it compiled (that's usually a good sign for me :) So now going to give it a shot. I'll check back in a bit to check if you left a comment. Thanks again.

Comment: #Revenues is getting created. It must be -- the fly in the ointment is no data from the sp. I get the fields back in an OUTPUT parameter as a CSV string, which are split for graph column labels with:                                                            SELECT  
LTRIM(STR([Year])) + '-' + STUFF([Month],1,0, REPLICATE('0', 2  - LEN([Month])))  
AS [Date]  
,Subtotal 
INTO #Revenues2
FROM #Revenues
-- for an OUTPUT parameter --
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT  
'],[' + [Date]   
FROM  #Revenues2  
ORDER BY '],[' + [Date]   
FOR XML PATH('')   
), 1, 2, '') + ']'

Comment: @cyberkiwi - Sorry! SELECT * FROM #Revenues2 at end of SP before DROP TABLE... returns the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @tab table
(
[month] int,
[year] int,
CustomerCode varchar(20),
SubTotal float 
)
insert into @tab
select
1,2012,'ccc',131.45 union all 
select
1,2012,'ccc',343.45 union all
select 
1,2012,'ELITE',643.92 union all
select 
2,2012,'ccc',131.45 union all 
select
2,2012,'ccc',343.45 union all
select 
2,2012,'ELITE',643.92 union all
select 
3,2012,'ccc',131.45 union all 
select
3,2012,'ccc',343.45 union all
select 
3,2012,'ELITE',643.92

;with cte as 
(
 select NTILE(3) OVER(partition by [month] ORDER BY [month]) AS [ntile],* from @tab
)
select * from cte
```

Even in your base query you need to add `partition by`, so that you will get correct output.

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be modified to only get the month and year dateparts.  The issue you are having with the same customer showing multiple times in the same month is due to the inclusion of i.DateOrdered in the select and group by clauses.

The following query should give you what you need.  Also, I suspect it is a typo on the next to last line of the query, but tsql doesn't have a TRIM() function only LTRIM and RTRIM.

```
SELECT 

LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))) AS [Month]   
,LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))) AS [Year]   
,c.CustomerCode 
,SUM(i.Jobprice) AS Subtotal  
,NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY SUM(i.JobPrice)) AS [ntile]
FROM Invoices i 
JOIN 
Customers c 
ON i.CustomerID = c.ID 
WHERE i.DateOrdered >= '1/1/2012'
AND i.DateOrdered <= '9/30/2012' 
GROUP BY YEAR(i.DateOrdered),  MONTH(i.DateOrdered),  c.CustomerCode
ORDER BY LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))),   
LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))),     
SUM(i.JobPrice), c.CustomerCode ASC
```

This gives these results

```
Month   Year    CustomerCode    Subtotal    ntile
 1      2012    ELITE            643.92      2
 1      2012    CCC            14900.23      5
 2      2012    CCC              135.99      1
 2      2012    CCI              370.47      1
 2      2012    NOC              766.84      3
 2      2012    ELITE           1428.26      4
 2      2012    VBC             5073.20      4
 3      2012    HUCC             759.66      2
 3      2012    ELITE           1402.95      3
 3      2012    CCC             8407.00      5
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to solve this problem without *double* ranking:

1. You need to get the largest sums per customer & month.
2. You then need, for every month, to retrieve the top five of the found sums.

Here's how I would approach this:

```
;
WITH MaxSubtotals AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CustomerID,
    MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateOrdered), 0),
    Subtotal  = MAX(SUM(JobPrice)) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Customer, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateOrdered), 0)
      ORDER BY SUM(JobPrice)
    )
  FROM Invoices
  GROUP BY
    CustomerID,
    DateOrdered
),
TotalsRanked AS (
  SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MonthDate,
    Subtotal,
    Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MonthDate ORDER BY Subtotal DESC)
  FROM MaxDailyTotals
)
SELECT
  Month = MONTH(i.MonthDate),
  Year  = YEAR(i.MonthDate),
  c.CustomerCode,
  i.Subtotal,
  i.Ranking
FROM TotalsRanked i
  INNER JOIN Customers ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE i.Ranking <= 5
;
```

The first CTE, `MaxSubtotals`, determines the maximum subtotals per customer & month. Involving `DISTINCT` and a window aggregating function, it is essentially a "shortcut" for the following two-step query:

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  MonthDate,
  Subtotal = MAX(Subtotal)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateOrdered), 0),
    Subtotal = SUM(JobPrice)
  FROM Invoices
  GROUP BY
    CustomerID,
    DateOrdered
) s
GROUP BY
  CustomerID,
  MonthDate
```

The other CTE, `TotalsRanked`, simply adds ranking numbers for the found susbtotals, partitioning by customer and month. As a final step, you only need to limit the rows to those that have rankings not greater than 5 (or whatever you might choose another time).

Note that using `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the rows in this case guarantees that you'll get no more than 5 rows with the `Ranking <= 5` filter. If there were two or more rows with the same subtotal, the would get distinct rankings, and in the end you might end up with an output like this:

```
   Month  Year  CustomerCode  Subtotal  Ranking
   -----  ----  ------------  --------  -------
   1      2012  CCC           1500.00   1
   1      2012  ELITE         1400.00   2
   1      2012  NOC           900.00    3
   1      2012  VBC           700.00    4
   1      2012  HUCC          700.00    5

-- 1      2012  ABC           690.00    6   -- not returned
-- 1      2012  ...           ...       ...
```

Even though there might be other customers with Subtotals of 700.00 for the same month, they wouldn't be returned, because they would be assigned rankings after 5.

You could use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to account for that. But note that you might end up with more than 5 *rows* per month then, with an output like this:

```
   Month  Year  CustomerCode  Subtotal  Ranking
   -----  ----  ------------  --------  -------
   1      2012  CCC           1500.00   1
   1      2012  ELITE         1400.00   2
   1      2012  NOC           900.00    3
   1      2012  VBC           700.00    4
   1      2012  HUCC          700.00    4
   1      2012  ABC           700.00    4

-- 1      2012  DEF           690.00    7   -- not returned
-- 1      2012  ...           ...       ...
```

Customers with subtotals less than 700.00 wouldn't make it to the output because they would have rankings starting with 7, which would correspond to the ranking of the first under-700.00 sum if ranked by `ROW_NUMBER()`.

And there's another option, `DENSE_RANK()`. You might want to use it if you want up to 5 distinct *sums* per month in your output. With `DENSE_RANK()` your output might contain even more rows per month than it would have with `RANK()`, but the number of distinct subtotals would be exactly 5 (or fewer if the original dataset can't provide you with 5). That is, your output might then look like this:

```
   Month  Year  CustomerCode  Subtotal  Ranking
   -----  ----  ------------  --------  -------
   1      2012  CCC           1500.00   1
   1      2012  ELITE         1400.00   2
   1      2012  NOC           900.00    3
   1      2012  VBC           700.00    4
   1      2012  HUCC          700.00    4
   1      2012  ABC           700.00    4
   1      2012  DEF           650.00    5
   1      2012  GHI           650.00    5
   1      2012  JKL           650.00    5

-- 1      2012  MNO           600.00    5   -- not returned
-- 1      2012  ...           ...       ...
```

Like `RANK()`, the `DENSE_RANK()` function assigns same rankings to identical values, but, *unlike* `RANK()`, it doesn't produce gaps in the ranking sequence.

---

References:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)